# Read only field for specific layout

Tags: page-layout

I have multiple layouts(l1,l2,l3..) for an object.I have a field on a standard detail page.When the user clicks the edit button from the L1 page layout , that field should not be editable only for that layout.If the user edit the detail page with L2 layout then the field should be editable.Is this achievable using standard out of the box functionality??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the field as `Read-only` from the page layouts clicking on `range` icon beside the field as follows:

[image: Read Only]

This field will be read-only specific to that particular layout.

If the user's profile has `Edit Read Only Fields` permission, then he can edit this field, even if it has been marked as read only.

Comment: Will that be read only for that specific page layout and not the profile?

Comment: @Samir Yes, it applies to the page layout/record type, regardless of the profile.